# Disable PhantomJS from generating a crash report

Tags: phantomjs

I have a bank of servers for generating snapshots of our Javascript heavy pages for SEO purposes. The servers use PhantomJS for rendering the pages, but occassionally the browser will crash, the server will handle the crash gracefully and try again, however, PhantomJS creates a file, e.g., `/tmp/7ffeb5fb-2986-56e2-4ade3815-693b6753.dmp`, every time it crashes for reporting bugs. The problems is our servers have limited diskspace and are eventually consuming all the disk. I couldn't find any mention in the documentation for disabling the file generation.

Is there a way, short of creating a cron job to periodically clean the tmp folder, to prevent the dump file from being generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching the source code I found that PhantomJS will disable crash dumps if you export a variable

`export PHANTOMJS_DISABLE_CRASH_DUMPS="on"`

[Source](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/235d072db5dc3d9b82d745eb817bfeddcba38595/src/crashdump.cpp#L148)